# Any program can record your singing or humming, and then create the musical notes of what you sing?

Tags: software-rec, music, audio-recording

I am looking for a program that can record a melody, that is record the humming of my voice and then convert said melody into the musical note version (akin to the sheets of music a pianoist uses).

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Songsmith.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/songsmith/

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3oGFogwcx-E

Comment: I am SO getting downvoted for this...

Comment: That has to be the cheesiest commercial ever made

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any free programs which do this, but [Finale](http://www.finalemusic.com/) (which is very expensive) can.

Comment: [Sibelius](http://www.sibelius.com/home/index_flash.html) is a competitor which can probably do the same thing, and there are cheaper products made by the same companies that _might_ also have that capability. But it's a reasonably complicated task so I wouldn't be too surprised if there's no free alternative.

Answer (score 1):

[Humming composer in the Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.igoogle.euphony&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5pZ29vZ2xlLmV1cGhvbnkiXQ..) can do this.

> Humming Composer can transform your humming to digital song that
>   played by piano, guitar, violin and other over 10 kinds of instrument.
>   This tool is precise and easy to use. Whenever you have the feeling to
>   hum a song, you can use it and share the  song to anyone with a few
>   operation. With this tool, you can also be a composer though you are
>   not a musician.

Answer (score 0):

There's an Android app [Humming Composer](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=%E5%93%BC%E6%AD%8C%E4%BD%9C%E6%9B%B2&c=apps) that can do this